# Unity3D iOS & Android embed / integrate into Xamarin project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

We are trying to embed a Unity3D project into a Xamarin Forms project.

First we had tried to embed the exported native Unity project into a Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS project:

First we converted the Unity Android and iOS projects to native library projects this seems to work nicely, the 3D graphics are shown and everything are good.

Bindings of the .aar binary file to a Xamarin Bindings Project also went pretty smooth only two warnings and no errors. The setup was identical to the native approach with a Xamarin.Android project using the DLL of the Binding project.

But under the test it fails with the error message "Failure to initialize! Your hardware does not support this application, sorry!". Because the Unity files use DLLs and other binary Data files, I cannot debug it.

Is this a known problem?

Can anyone point out,what we are doing wrong?

Are there a better approach? Please guide us.

Thank you.